# App is not shown in launcher for 4.0.3

Tags: android, launcher

I can install my app on:

- emulators 2.2, 2.3.3;
- my phone 2.2.2;

And it's shown in launcher and widgets manager.

But after installing it on emulator 4.0.3, it is *not* shown in launcher and widgets manager.

Here is manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".handlers.MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/my_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Would you help me?

Thanks,

**Edited:**

This is such a stupid question. I tried to scroll the app list vertically. But in 4.0.3, the list is horizontal.

:-)

So there is no problem with my app. I'm sorry...

Comment: Is it shown in Settings -> App?

Comment: Yes it is. And there are two things I can do: **1)** After installing it, open it by button `Open` next to button `Done`. And it works fine without any error. **2)** After that, I can only uninstall it via app manager. Even if I reboot the emulator, I can't see it on launcher/ widget manager.

Comment: How about installing in directly from Eclipse. Run As -> Android App. Does it show on launcher?

Comment: @Calvin, No it doesn't  :-( I have some other apps, they are all working properly in 4.0.3. Except this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your app widget will not show up in the widgets list until the user runs one of your activities. This behavior is new to Android 3.1.

There is nothing obviously wrong with the activity, though you might try removing `Theme.NoDisplay` and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @haibison: That means you are left with "debug by binary search" -- take a project that works and incrementally modify it to look more like the project that does not work, until it breaks, at which point the last change you made is the source of your difficulty.